# i am just tried to create an sql query but not getting

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

I have two tables. The left side table is Bin and the Right side table is Bout. In_id means an order in which they are batting, Out_id means an order in which they are out from the game. Report1 below shows the answer I want, i.e. those who made a partnership. I am not getting any idea on how to write a query to retrieve the data which is in report 1. That is the answer I actually want. How to write a query for that? Your help would be appreciated!

Comment: I see no effort here :-(

Comment: Name is not needed in the Out table - you're just duplicating what's already in the Batting table. A good database design doesn't write the same information twice.

Comment: @Meh.  Welcome to StackOverflow.  You may find [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) useful.  :)

Comment: am not getting logic how to solve this ,stucked,

Comment: i want the result like in  report1 who made partership, but not getting any ideaa!!!

Answer (score -1):

```
select 
  s1.names,
  s2.names 
from 
  IN_TABLE,
  OUT_TABLE s1,s2 
where 
  s1.IN_ID = s2.IN_ID;
```

(where s1 and s2 are alias)

or

```
select 
  left_table.name, 
  right_table.name as Report1 
from 
  left_table,
  right_table 
where 
  left_table.IN_ID = right_table.IN_ID
```

please try and let us know if this solves your problem.
Also, see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KTvYHEntvn8 for more knowledge.

Comment: @Meh: Please can you provide the query that you have tried?

Comment: Your first query isn't even correct syntax (it will think s2 is another table name) - did you actually try and test it? And Why are you using comma-separated JOINS when the ANSI SQL standard INNER JOIN has existed for 20 years or more? It's more readable and obvious, and is the official standard way to do it. Comma-separated joins are deprecated in many databases - certainly you should not be writing any new code using that syntax. The youtube video you've linked to shows how to write an INNER JOIN the proper way - you've linked to it for further education, but you don't follow it yourself!

Comment: Thanks, @Adyson for your feedback, appreciate it :)

Answer (score -1):

This is multi step approach. table 1 refers to left side table i.e. batting id table and table 2 refers to right side table i.e out id table in your data.
new.table1, new.table2, new.table3, new.table4 are temporary table. Correct column name as per your data. Hope you will get your result. Comment if find any issue.

```
Create temporary table new.table1
select OUT.ID, IN.ID, Name, (IN.ID - OUT.ID) AS DIFF from table2;


Create temporary table new.table2
select OUT.ID, IN.ID, Name, (OUT.ID + 1) AS NEW.ID from new.table1 where DIFF <= 0;


Create temporary table new.table3
select OUT.ID, IN.ID, Name, DIFF AS NEW.ID from new.table1 where DIFF > 0;


Create temporary table new.table4
select OUT.ID, IN.ID, Name, NEW.ID from new.table2
UNION ALL
select OUT.ID, IN.ID, Name, NEW.ID from new.table3;

---Final Output

select A.Name, B.Name AS Name2 from new.table4 A, table1 B where A.NEW.ID = B.IN.ID;
```

Comment: 1) Not sure what all the DIFF stuff is meant to be about? What is the purpose of all that? I think it's a distraction from the real question. You should explain the logic, at least. 2) Why are you using comma-separated JOINS when the ANSI SQL standard INNER JOIN has existed for 20 years or more? It's more readable and obvious, and is the official standard way to do it. Comma-separated joins are deprecated in many databases - certainly you should not be writing any new code using that syntax.

Comment: 1. If you observe in outid data that the difference between the IN_ID and OUT_ID actually gives you other partner id from Batting id data. However this applies only when difference (IN_ID - OUT_ID) is positive. If difference is negative or zero add 1 to the OUT_ID and then that will give other partner id.

Comment: Nope, you've lost me . Can you give a worked example using the OP's data? The OUT_ID already **is** the other partner, based on the sample output in screenshot. And anyway I would suspect this pattern is just an accident of this particular data sample, I doubt we can always assume it would be nearly ordered like that.

Comment: P.S. your code doesn't even compile, either. Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4d1e4b87c9e01e74e9f7a23bc89c30c4

Comment: I think you've a) made unprovable assumptions about the patterns of data, b) massively overcomplicated a simple problem, and c) not tested your code properly before posting.

Comment: Even if we remove all the syntax and other errors to get runnable code, it still makes absolutely no sense whatsoever, and produces nothing useful. Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=77aab64d119dc6e661ebab97348f3f53 . It's not even clear what all the temp tables are supposed to be for, they never get populated with anything. Do you program in SQL very often, or not?

Comment: Perhaps you meant this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=85c0bb00bbd78c429008633020f9d779 . but it still doesn't get the right result. And it's still way more complicated than just joining to the batters table, which is the obvious and simple solution.

Answer (score -2):

You need a join or a subquery.
Lets take a look of a join

```
Select 
  leftTable.Name, 
  rightTable.Name 
from 
  leftTable 
  join rightTable 
    on leftTable.IN_ID = rightTable.In_ID
```

Edited: left to leftTable and right to rightTable